# Error "AADSTS50194: Application 'xxxxxxxx' is not configured as a multi-tenant application" when using 'azure/msal-browser' reactjs package

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-managed-identity, msal-react

I have a SPA app that is trying to login to Azure AD using  'azure/msal-browser' reactjs package.

The app is set to use a single tenant authentication at Azure App registration.
The `authConfig.js` file is set to use single tenant Authentication as well, but i keep getting the error:

```
AADSTS50194: Application 'xxxxxxxx' is not configured as a multi-tenant application
```

I found similar posts but all then point to set authority parameter, what i had already done.

The scenario i am trying to implement is the silent login with page redirect. This is the official [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/VanillaJSTestApp2.0/app/onPageLoad) that i'm basing my implementation.

Here the steps to recreate:

1. install msal-browser
2. Configure the AuthConfig.js file according with your app registration:

   ```
   const msalConfig = {
     auth: {
        clientId: "Application (client) ID",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Directory (tenant) ID>/",
        redirectUri: "<app url(must be a allowed URL redirect for SPA application type)>"
   },
   ...
   export const loginRequest = {
       scopes: ["openid", "User.Read"]
   };
   ```
3. And the code to acquire the token:

   ```
    import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
    import { loginRequest} from "../../authConfig";

    // this is my simplified version of the method `getTokenRedirect` present in the sample.

    export const acquireIdToken = async (msalInstanceParam) => {

        const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(loginRequest);
        const activeAccount = msalInstance.getActiveAccount(); 
        const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

        const request = {
            scopes: ["User.Read"],
            account: activeAccount || accounts[0]
        };

        const authResult = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);//throws http code 400 error with message 'AADSTS50194 ...'
        return authResult.idToken
    };
   ```

The funny thing is that i'm able to login successfully, be redirect to the SPA app, get the token, retrieve the user name from the token, but for some reason the app calls https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token and i get this error in the console.

Any clues?

The browser log (updated):

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-react@1.3.1 : Info - useAccount - Updating account
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@2.22.1 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectStart
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-react@1.3.1 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress from startup to handleRedirect
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : [78728aa2-9ecd-4399-994a-4d8ab8801b13] : msal.js.browser@2.22.1 : Info - handleRedirectPromise called but there is no interaction in progress, returning null.
RequestInterceptor.tsx:27 Wrapped Fetch started for resource planning
GetToken.js:22 acquire token ...
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-react@1.3.1 : Info - useAccount - Updating account
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@2.22.1 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectEnd
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-react@1.3.1 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectEnd results in setting inProgress from handleRedirect to none
RequestInterceptor.tsx:27 Wrapped Fetch started for resource https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
authConfig.js:36 [Thu, 23 Jun 2022 17:09:59 GMT] : @azure/msal-react@1.3.1 : Info - useAccount - Updating account
RequestInterceptor.tsx:27 Wrapped Fetch started for resource https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
RequestInterceptor.tsx:27 Wrapped Fetch started for resource https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
RequestInterceptor.tsx:33
RequestInterceptor.tsx:33          POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token 400 (Bad Request)
```

Apparently, by inspecting the log, the endpoint discovery is providing the authority url that overrides the setting:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Comment: In this line `const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(loginRequest);`, what does loginRequest contain? Does it have the authority?

Comment: Just a constant that set scopes. It is defined at 'AuthConfig.js' file. The name is misguiding, it comes with the sample.

Comment: Because you need to set the authority to PublicClientApplication, so I'm thinking that's missing here.

Comment: In fact, i did not set. i passed loginRequest as parameter instead of msalConfig as you make me notice. Somehow i was getting the token so i didn't question myself about not getting the settings from the msalConfig  constant. That could be because msal lib was getting the clientId from the environment variable. (in my real code in set the structure msalConfig from environment variables). So, basically i mess it up good. It is working fine now, i clean it up and made other changes that may had impact so i can't determine if this was the all problem without rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

First, authority needs to target the `organizations` (for work or student accounts) or `common` (for all the aformentioned plus personal accounts) endpoints and not the tenant specific. E.g.

```js
{
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/", 
  //  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/", 
}
```

Finally, you need to configure your app registration as multi-tenant. [Update its app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#configure-the-app-manifest) and ensure `signInAudience`is set to `AzureADMultipleOrgs` or `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`.  The latter requires `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to be set to `2`.

Comment: Sure about that? i put it to work by setting the authority to: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId from app registration>'

Comment: Yes, otherwise you will get an AADSTS90072 error. Unless you've added the external tenant user as guest which will make it a single tenant app call.